# Registering recipe for Minecraft with Forge on IntelliJ

Tags: java, minecraft-modding, modding

I'm using Forge on IntelliJ IDEA to make a mod for Minecraft, and I think I am stuck on where I need to register a recipe for an item.

**How I got to that idea:**
I tested it out and everything worked. No bugs/errors: The item that would be made with the recipe (a rubber band) was available right away in creative mode. However, when I was trying to do the recipe part for creating the rubber band, which would include getting a dandelion that leads to an achievement(?) that shows the player they would then be able to make a rubber band with dandelions, the achievement only showed the regular recipe that's in the original game.

I know the setup of the files that import other methods works because I tried it out with [this](https://wiki.mcjty.eu/modding/index.php?title=Tutorial_1.18_Episode_1) example. It also shows that the rubber_band.json was made in the resources, so my guess is that the part that went wrong is most likely how I did not include the registration of the recipe for the rubber band. I'm just unsure how to get that settled.

Here is what I have so far:

```java
public class Recipes  extends RecipeProvider {

    public Recipes(DataGenerator generatorIn) {
        super(generatorIn);
    }

    @Override
    protected void buildCraftingRecipes(Consumer<FinishedRecipe> consumer) {
        ShapelessRecipeBuilder.shapeless(Registration.RUBBER_BAND.get())
                .requires(Items.DANDELION, 9)
                .unlockedBy("has_dandelion", has(Items.DANDELION))
                .save(consumer);
    }
}
```

^ with imports, this is the recipes (the only one I have so far)

```java
    public static final RegistryObject<Item> RUBBER_BAND = ITEMS.register("rubber_band", () -> new Item(ITEM_PROPERTIES));
    // public static final TagKey<Item> DANDELION_ITEM = TagKey.create(Registry.ITEM_REGISTRY, new ResourceLocation(glow.MODID, "dandelion_item"));

        public static final DeferredRegister<RecipeType<?>> RECIPES = DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.RECIPE_SERIALIZERS.getRegistryName(), glow.MODID);
    public static final RegistryObject<RecipeType<CraftingRecipe>> RUBBER_BAND_RECIPE = RECIPES.register("rubber_band_recipe", () -> new Recipe<ITEM_RECIPE>);
```

^ this is towards registration

```java
singleTexture(Registration.RUBBER_BAND.getId().getPath(), mcLoc("item/generated"), "layer0", modLoc("item/rubber_band"));
```

^ this is towards ItemModelProvider

```java
tag(Registration.DANDELION_ITEM)
                .add(Registration.RUBBER_BAND.get());
```

^ these are the tags

```java
add(Registration.RUBBER_BAND.get(), "Rubber band");
```

^ this is the name

I am following [this tutorial](https://wiki.mcjty.eu/modding/index.php?title=Tutorial_1.18_Episode_1) and [this tutorial](https://wiki.mcjty.eu/modding/index.php?title=Tutorial_1.18_Episode_2) to get the format organized (and understand things better). I am also using [this doc](https://nekoyue.github.io/ForgeJavaDocs-NG/javadoc/1.18.2/net/minecraft/core/Registry.html) to see what I'm looking for, though I'm still not getting a good grasp on reading it.

Once more, my goal is to be able to craft the rubber band.

This is what it should look like at the crafting table:

[image: Crafting table recipe]

The player should also unlock the recipe when picking up the dandelion:

[image: Unlocking recipe when picking up dandelion]

Also, this is for game 1.18.2. Thank you in advance!

I have not yet used the `Recipes` class. I have been trying to follow along with [this](https://github.com/McJty/TutorialV3/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/tutorialv3/setup/Registration.java), which is the most recent version of the tutorial author's, but this also does not mention `Recipes` while it includes the class.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Minecraft modding, but it almost looks like you're overwriting the Recipe class completely, no?  I can see you have `public class Recipes`, but where are you doing `new Recipes("recipe")`?

Comment: Back when I used Forge, you just called `GameRegistry.registerShapelessRecipe` in your mod's init function.

Comment: Where does your `Recipes` class get used?

Comment: @dockeryZ @user253751 I have edited the question to include why I do not have `Recipes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I missed adding `new Recipes()` in the class `DataGenerators`

````java
@Mod.EventBusSubscriber(modid = glow.MODID, bus = Mod.EventBusSubscriber.Bus.MOD)
public class DataGenerators {

    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void gatherData(GatherDataEvent event) {
        DataGenerator generator = event.getGenerator();
        if (event.includeServer()) {
            generator.addProvider(new Recipes(generator)); // this was previously commented out
            // generator.addProvider(new LootTables(generator));
            BlockTags blockTags = new BlockTags(generator, event.getExistingFileHelper());
            generator.addProvider(blockTags);
            generator.addProvider(new ItemTags(generator, blockTags, event.getExistingFileHelper()));
        }
        if (event.includeClient()) {
            generator.addProvider(new BlockStates(generator, event.getExistingFileHelper()));
            generator.addProvider(new ItemModels(generator, event.getExistingFileHelper()));
            generator.addProvider(new LanguageProvider(generator, "en_us"));
        }
    }
}
```
````